# Motorola Atrix 4g force close error

Tags: android, motorola

Sorry this isn't a programming issue.
I am using Motorola Atrix 4g. It worked like a boss for almost 6/7 months. Recently it started showing Force close com.motorola.service.main and restart the phone, then again force close and restart. After restarting almost 10 times it showed the screen. Then I factory reset the set, thought it will solve the problem.

But after resetting the phone it still gives error "com.motorola.service.main has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again" and then force close, but it doesn't restart now. So I can still use the phone. And I live in Bangladesh, so there is no servicing center available for this.

Anyone faced this before? or does anyone have any clue how to fix it?

Comment: Belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time I write this, its been 8 hours since I did this work around change and not observed the annoying com.motorola.service.main pop up.

Problem: occurs when phone is syncing email or accessing email accounts, com.motorola.service.main pop-up.

Fix: In my case I was using yahoo mail, aol mail and msn's hotmail (and gmail which is standard). I install yahoo mail app, aol mail app and hotmail app using the phone's "Google Play". Once the mail apps are install, I have not had a pop-up occur. Of course this is only for email accounts that have separate apps available.